# Workflow Rule to check for null lookup

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to write a very simple workflow where if the Case Contact is NULL do some action.

In my Rule Criteria, I've tried:

```
isNull( ContactId )
```

However, this doesn't seem to trigger the workflow.

```
|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]isNull( {!ID:Contact} )|Values:ContactId=null
|WF_CRITERIA_END|false
```

What is the correct way to do this check?

Comment: Worst case you could pull the `Id` into a formula and evaluate that. Hopefully someone will have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested with `ISBLANK(ContactId)` and it seems to work:

[image]

Comment: I had tried that earlier and I thought it didn't work, but I must have been doing something to prevent the workflow from firing.  Looks like if you just edit and save the workflow without changing the contact field, it doesn't fire it again.